# Mocking constructor to force my way into a conditional

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

So I'm doing unit testing and I need to make it into a conditional based upon the below condition (i.e I want the condition to be true)

```
if(foo.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(foo.body).length === 0) {
.
.
.
}
```

My mock up looks like this so far.  This doesn't crash but it won't go into the conditional as I would like.

```
let foo = {
    body:()=> jest.fn()
}
```

I've also tried the below and noticed that the length returned is always 1.

```
let foo = {
        body:{
            constructor: Object
        }
    }
```

Not sure what I need to do to get the length of foo.body to be 0 as well as have the foo.body.constructor be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two conditions are that `foo.body` is an `Object` and that `foo.body` does not have any `keys`, so this will get you inside the conditional:

```
const foo = {
  body: {}  // Object with no keys
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let foo = {
  body: {
    aMockedKey: () => jest.fn()
  }
}
```

The second condition is testing keys of foo.body

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't seem to work.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding what aMockedKey should be in my context.